# How does Textile detect and remove <script> tags?

Tags: php, regex, formatting, textile

I'm using Textile for content editing on a site.  Only trusted users have access to editing.

I want to insert insert gists from GitHub: `<script src="http://gist.github.com/#####.js"></script>` but Textile removes these with: "`[removed][removed]`".

I've searched through the Textile PHP class for how and where it detects this and removes it, but it escapes me. I found the [Textile tag filtering for Ruby](http://jeff.jones.be/technology/articles/textile-filtering-with-redcloth/), is there anything similar for the PHP class?

Comment: Chances are it's calling the native php [`strip_tags`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) along with some regex for the replacement method.

Comment: No such luck.  I don't find them using `strip_tags` anywhere in the class. I don't even find the word "removed" anywhere, which is what it replaces them with.

Comment: seach for the word `script` then, possibly it's all being done via basic string search/replace.

Comment: Yeah, that was the first thing I tried. It isn't there either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I feel like an idiot. It was CodeIgniter filtering the $POST data that removed it.

**For reference:** Textile does **not** automatically remove `<script>` or other tags.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using regexp, with the function [preg_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php):

```
/<[^<]+?>/i
```

If you dont need the replace, just use [strip_tags()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) function.

Comment: Is that to remove the <script> tags?  I need it to keep them; the problem is it *is* removing them. :)  I wasn't able to find that regex or anything too similar so far.